# Office Ui react commandBar show menus on mouseover

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, typescript, office-ui-fabric-react

I have top navigation which is using office Ui react commandBar, where i have to click on the menu to show the 2nd level of the menu. Is there anyway to add the hover effect to this commandBar or class to make sure on mouseover the 2nd level of menus are displayed ?

```
const CommandBarProps: ICommandBarStyleProps = {
    theme: theme,
    
}; 

   
const buttonStyle: IButtonStyles = {
        root: {
            ':hover': {
                backgroundColor: "darken(someColor, 0.3) !important",
                
            },
            backgroundColor: "#27348a",
            color: "#fff",
            justifyContent:"center !important",
            letterSpacing: "1px",
            
            
        },
        menuIcon: {
            color: "#fff",
            justifyContent: "center !important",
            letterSpacing:"1px",
            display:"flex"
        }
    };

        <CommandBar
                            className={styles.commandBar}
                            {...CommandBarProps}
                            items={commandBarItems}
                        />
```